# Firebase real-time database rule for Admin SDK

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-admin-sdk

How to write read and write rules for a node in **Firebase real-time database**, so that it can be accessed only through the **Firebase Admin SDK** and not by the users?

If I write rules in the following way:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "MyData": {
      ".read": false,
      ".write": false
    }
  }
}
```

Users won't be able to read and write the node **MyData**. But will **Firebase admin SDK** be able to read and write that node?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, access to Firebase products (including Realtime Database) via the Firebase Admin SDK is always 100% privileged to perform reads and writes of all data within those products, assuming that the SDK was initialized with a service account for the project that hosts the product.

Comment: And what about validate rules?

Comment: Rules don't affect normal access by the Admin SDK.